# Python - an extremely odd behavior of function lstrip

Tags: python

I have encountered a very odd behavior of built-in function `lstrip`.

I will explain with a few examples:

```
print 'BT_NAME_PREFIX=MUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME_PREFIX=') # UV
print 'BT_NAME_PREFIX=NUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME_PREFIX=') # UV
print 'BT_NAME_PREFIX=PUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME_PREFIX=') # UV
print 'BT_NAME_PREFIX=SUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME_PREFIX=') # SUV
print 'BT_NAME_PREFIX=mUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME_PREFIX=') # mUV
```

As you can see, the function trims one additional character **sometimes**.

I tried to model the problem, and noticed that it persisted if I:

- Changed `BT_NAME_PREFIX` to `BT_NAME_PREFIY`
- Changed `BT_NAME_PREFIX` to `BT_NAME_PREFIZ`
- Changed `BT_NAME_PREFIX` to `BT_NAME_PREF`

Further attempts have made it **even more weird**:

```
print 'BT_NAME=MUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME=') # UV
print 'BT_NAME=NUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME=') # UV
print 'BT_NAME=PUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME=') # PUV - different than before!!!
print 'BT_NAME=SUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME=') # SUV
print 'BT_NAME=mUV'.lstrip('BT_NAME=') # mUV
```

Could someone please explain what on earth is going on here?

I know I might as well just use array-slicing, but I would still like to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `lstrip`?

Comment: `lstrip` does not do what you think it is supposed to be doing. Quoting from the documentation: "If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead."

Comment: `help(''.lstrip)`...

Comment: @Cameron: I have now (have only used it for white spaces up until now). Thanks.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala -- Why not `help(str.lstrip)`?  It feels a bit more explicit to me... :-P

Comment: Well, `help('BT_NAME_PREFIX=MUV'.lstrip)`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how `lstrip` works.  It treats the characters you pass in as a bag and it strips characters that are in the bag until it finds a character that isn't in the bag.

Consider:

```
'abc'.lstrip('ba')  # 'c'
```

It is **not** removing a substring from the start of the string.  To do that, you need something like:

```
if s.startswith(prefix):
    s = s[len(prefix):]
```

e.g.:

```
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> prefix = 'foo'
>>> if s.startswith(prefix):
...     s = s[len(prefix):]
... 
>>> s
'bar'
```

Or, I suppose you could use a regular expression:

```
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('^foo', '', s)
'bar'
```

Comment: Damn, I should have checked more carefully, wasn't paying too much attention (I have mostly just used it for white spaces). Thanks!!!

Comment: @barakmanos -- I think I probably knew the answer to this one off the top of my head because it's bitten me a time or two as well.  I actually really wish there was `stripprefix` and `stripsuffix` methods :-)

Answer (score 1):

The argument given to `lstrip` is a list of things to remove from the left of a string, on a character by character basis. The phrase is not considered, only the characters themselves.

> S.lstrip([chars]) -> string or unicode
>
> Return a copy of the string S with leading whitespace removed. If
>   chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead. If
>   chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping

You could solve this in a flexible way using regular expressions (the `re` module):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('^BT_NAME_PREFIX=', '', 'BT_NAME_PREFIX=MUV')
MUV
```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake for not bothering to read the docs.

Comment: I realized that's probably what happened when I saw your reputation :) Good question nonetheless.